# returning a char array from a char function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am doing this

```
char *draw_line(int n, char ch)
{
    char *line = new char[50];
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        line[i] = ch;
    return line;
}
```

and while calling the function I am writing this:

```
char *res_line = draw_line(50, '=');
cout<<*res_line;
```

but instead of getting `=` printed 50 times in the console window, it just show `=` sign one time. My main aim is to return the `=` or any character as many times I want and output 
the same to a text file. That's it.

Comment: your "string" is not null terminated. And use `std::string`

Comment: @quantdev thats not the problem in this case

Comment: If you think `n` and `50` are secretly related, you're right. once you fix the terminator, try `cout << ch50`. And *plz* consider just using `std::string(50,ch)`. Use the standard lib. It's whats for dinner.

Comment: so it means I need to terminate it first with a null. and why should i use `std::string`

Comment: @texasbruce : it clearly is A problem

Comment: I imagine they suggest using `std::string` because it can be safer and more versatile (and because C++ standard); however, if you want to use char[] or char*, then more power to you in my opinion.  It just means you may run into more problems to overcome.  A learning experience, if you ask me.

Comment: @Serge One important reason to use `std::string` is that it won't leak memory.  (Of course, _if_ he can accept a maximum `n`, it's possible to write a thread safe version using a static variable, and avoid all dynamic allocation completely.)

Comment: you question is tagged c++ but you are not doing things the c++ way. Any malloc is usally an error; learn to use c++ string type; etc.

Comment: @JamesKanze That's along the lines of what I was going for, when I said "safer"... though I suppose it wasn't very helpful that I didn't enumerate the different problems that could arise.

Answer (score 5):

```
cout<<*res_line;
```

is printing one char because `*res_line` is `char`, not `char*`.

Write:

```
cout<<res_line;
```

**But** wait — that is **not** going to work either because `res_line` is NOT null-terminated.

Use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` — **avoid explicit memory allocation**, use RAII idiom instead:

```
std::string draw_line(int n, char ch)
{
    return {n, ch}; //C++11
}
```

So simple!

Or if you use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> draw_line(int n, char ch)
{
    return {n, ch}; //C++11
}
```

which is almost same.

In C++03, however, you've to write:

```
return std::string(n, ch);        //in the first case
return std::vector<char>(n, ch);  //in the second case
```

That is, invoke the constructor explicitly.

Comment: It's worth noting that the result of `draw_line` is not null terminated. (You should probably put that in your answer.)

Comment: +1 for `std::vector`. `std::string` is just as good because it is element-wise accessible in the same way `vector` is, plus it is made to be used with characters.

Answer (score 2):

The valid code will look as

```
char* draw_line( int n, char ch )
{
    char *ch2= new char[n + 1]();

    std::memset( ch2, ch, n );

    return ch2;
}

//...

char *ch50 = draw_line(50,'=');
cout << ch50;
//...
delete []ch50;
```

Take into account this statement

```
char *ch2= new char[n + 1]();
```

But it would be much better to write simply

```
std::cout << std::string( 50, '=' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* draw_line(int n, char ch)
{
    char *ch2= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1)); // (n+1) here
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // < instead of <=
        ch2[i]=ch;
    ch2[n] = 0; // terminator
    return ch2;
}

char *ch50 = draw_line(50,'=');
cout<< ch50; // changed from *ch50 to ch50
```

**ADDON**: look at [string-fill constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

```
cout << string(50, '=');
```